# MGF of Standard sample mean

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

Given $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ $i.i.d$ with mean $\mu$ ,  variance $\sigma^2$ and MGF $X_j = M$ and $Z_n = \sqrt{n}\big(\frac{\tilde X_n - \mu}{\sigma}\big)$

Find MGF of $Z_n$ in terms of $M$.

What I managed to do is the following:

$$MGF_{Z_n}(t) = E\big(e^{t\sqrt{n}\big(\frac{\tilde X_n - \mu}{\sigma}\big)}\big) = $$
$$ E\big(e^{\frac{t\sqrt n}{\sigma}(\tilde X - \mu)}\big) = e^{-\mu \frac{t\sqrt n}{\sigma}}E\big(e^{\frac{t\sqrt n}{\sigma}\tilde X}\big ) =$$
$$ e^{-\mu \frac{t\sqrt n}{\sigma}}E\big(e^{\frac{t}{\sigma\sqrt n}(X_1 + ... + X_N)}\big) = $$
$$e^{-\mu \frac{t\sqrt n}{\sigma}}E\big(e^{\frac{t}{\sigma\sqrt n}X_i}\big)^n $$

I don't know how to go from  $E\big(e^{\frac{t}{\sigma\sqrt n}X_i}\big) $ to M which is $E(e^{tX_i})$. I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: You are already finished because, if $M(t):=\mathbb{E}e^{tX_i}$ denotes the mgf of $X_i$, then your last line is the same as  $$e^{-\mu \frac{t\sqrt n}{\sigma}}\left(M(t/(\sqrt{n}\sigma)\right)^n.$$

Comment: Ah right, M is a function not a constant :-). Thank you.